# Reference counting return value of MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using Objective-C without ARC and want to know if I need to free the device returned by `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` when used like so:

```
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
```

I am not sure how `id<MTLDevice>` works to maintain a reference count. Based on the naming conventions for memory management, I am assuming `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` does not add reference (but could be wrong), but maybe assigning to `id<MTLDevice>` results in a retain being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to release the object when you're done with it. For C functions (rather than Objective-C messages), the relevant naming convention is the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). Because the function has "Create" in the name, it returns a +1 reference that you are responsible for releasing. (The fact that it's returning an Objective-C type rather than a Core Foundation type isn't important.)

As to `id<MTLDevice>`, that's `id`, the generic object type of Objective-C, with a protocol designation `<MTLDevice>` indicating that the object pointed to by `device` conforms to the `MTLDevice` protocol. (Somewhat oddly, that's actually more restrictive than `id` alone, since the compiler will then warn if you try to invoke methods other than those supported by `MTLDevice` and its super-protocols.) Not that the object is of some concrete class behind the scenes, it's just a private implementation detail.